# Configurable background drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have been working on android on some time, but there is a common problem which i face many times. The problem is there are multiple view where in i assign the view a background drawable for background, such as:

[image: view with same style but with solid colour and border as green and dark green respectively]

[image: view with same style but with solid colour and border as grey and dark grey respectively]

As can be seen in the above example the background drawable for both the views is same but only difference in the both background drawables xml file is the solid and stroke colour. Is there any other better way to do this where i just create a generic background drawable and change the colour of the components from xml and id not possible in xml instead of creating a new drawable each time for each solid colour and stroke colour variation.

Comment: you can take reference of that drawable in java and do what ever you want
 --------------------------------------------
final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_id);
        shape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));

Comment: Is there and another way by using xml?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in XML. However, it is possible using Java.

```
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet))
```